# what is the limit of $\sum_{i=1}^n1/(2n+i)$ if $n$ goes to infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> what is the limit of $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2n+i}$$ if $n$ goes to infinity?

I've tried that the sequences is increasing and bounded by $\frac{1}{2}$, but I don't have idea to find the limit.

By wolfarmalpha, its said that the limit is $\ln \frac{3}{2}$, but I don't know where it is come from.

Can someone give me some hints?

Comment: What do you know about Integral and Riemann Sums?

Answer (score 4):

The summand equals $$\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{2\frac{i}{n}+1}.$$

Can you interpret your sum as the Riemann sum of some function over the interval $[0,1]$? Hint: take an equipartition with $\Delta x_i=\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: This answer is not particularly helpful.

Comment: @M.Wind Why not? I've nearly solved the whole thing. I didn't write the final solution itself because OP asked for a hint. Saying any more than I said would give a full solution.

Comment: @M.Wind It seems to me that only the OP can make that assertion.